# ContourLabels in implicit ContourPlot

Tags: plotting

Can [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html) label contours when the plotting implicit curves?  For example,

```
ContourPlot[Abs[Sin[x] Sin[y]] == 0.5, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
ContourLabels -> True]
```

produces

[image: Mathematica graphics]

with no visible labels, as do

```
ContourPlot[Abs[Sin[x] Sin[y]] == 0.5, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
ContourLabels -> "x"]

ContourPlot[Abs[Sin[x] Sin[y]] == 0.5, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
ContourLabels -> {"x"}]
```

and every other variant I can think of.  Miraculously,

```
ContourPlot[Abs[Sin[x] Sin[y]] == 0.5, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
ContourLabels -> {Null, Tooltip[Null, "x"] &}]
```

*does* produce customizable Tooltips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify `Contours` rather than using `Equal` in the first argument

```
ContourPlot[Abs[Sin[x] Sin[y]], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
    ContourLabels -> (Text[Framed[#3], {#1, #2}, Background -> White] &),
                Contours -> {0.5}, ContourStyle -> Blue, ContourShading -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I seem to recall this approach from older versions.  The contours appear a bit thinner, but it's acceptable.  I had tried it myself with `ContourShading -> False` and those contours were unacceptably thin!

Comment: @ChrisK Replacing the style by `ContourStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.01], Blue]` makes them thick